# Which parameter is applied when there are serveal lambda variables in a function?

Tags: android, kotlin

Normally, when the latest parameter of a function is a lambda , I can use such as `function(first,...) {latest}` to pass the lambda parameter.

The Code A and Code B are from the official sample [project](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid).

There are three lambda parameters in fun `NiaFilledButton` which are `text`, `leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon` in Code A.

When the author invoke the function with Code B, which parameter will be assigned with the value of `Text(text = "Enabled")` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun NiaFilledButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    small: Boolean = false,
    colors: ButtonColors = NiaButtonDefaults.filledButtonColors(),
    text: @Composable () -> Unit,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
NiaFilledButton(onClick = {}) {
   Text(text = "Enabled")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a lambda argument outside of parentheses, it's always the **last** argument to the function. This is true regardless of what other arguments you pass inside the parentheses, named or otherwise. You can only use the trailing lambda syntax when the last argument is a function. You can read more in the docs for [passing trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas).

That means that your Code B will try to pass the lambda as `trailingIcon`. With your code A, this doesn't compile, because as you pointed out in a comment, there's no value provided for the required parameter `text`. In the sample project you linked to, there's actually an [additional overload](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/607c24e7f7399942e278af663ea4ad350e5bbc3a/core/designsystem/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/core/designsystem/component/Button.kt#L54) for the function which does not require the `text` parameter. That's why the function call shown in your Code B is valid.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think you are correct.  If  Code B will pass the lambda as `trailingIcon`, the app should crash because the parameter `text: @Composable () -> Unit` isn't assigned with a vaule.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my answer. You're right that as it stands, Code A and Code B from your question would cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this Kotlin Playground is useful.

```
fun main() {
    foo(o= { println("o")} ) { println("b") }
}

fun foo(
    o: () -> Unit,
    b: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    c: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    o()
    c?.invoke()
}
```

The output is `o b` because is the **last** and compile won't allow you to use more than one non-parenthesized argument.

Comment: @Sams answer should be accepted since I didn't fully know about the last argument and discovered it a few seconds after he posted while I was typing that example in the playground while I think this helps as well.